# Printing only a portion of the column contents .txt file

Tags: regex, perl, text

Ordinarily to conditionally print specific columns from a .txt file I would utilise:

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$F[5]" if $F[1] > 0 && $F[0] =~ /^A$/ && $F[3] =~ /^A$/' input.txt > output.txt
```

i.e. print column 1/2/6 in-full if the match criteria are met.

This however prints the full contents of column 1/2/6.

If for example the 6th column contained "ID=A08AY;ID2=12309A;Name=TEST"

Is it possible as a 1-liner to print "A08AY" only and ignore the rest of the column contents? If so, how?

Comment: Some sample input data/expected output might be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the ID, store it in a variable:

```
perl -lane '($id) = $F[5] =~ /ID=(.*?);/,
            print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$id"
                if $F[1] > 0 && $F[0] =~ /^A$/ && $F[3] =~ /^A$/'
```

`*?` is a "frugal quantifier", it matches the shortest string possible, thereofre the match will end at the first `;`.

`($id)` is in parentheses which forces list context, so the match returns the capture group.

Comment: So this would match "ID:" independently of it's position/column number?

Answer (score 1):

If the bit you want is always in the same position within the sixth column, then you could use `split()` to get the relevant part of `$F[5]`.

```
$id = (split /;=/, $F[5])[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had problem looking at accepted answer so rewrite:

```
perl -lane'
  next unless $F[1] >0 and $F[0] =~ /^A$/ and $F[3] =~ /^A$/;
  print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$1" if $F[5] =~ /ID=(.*?);/;
'
```